# Wordpress WooCommerce permalinks issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

So I've just downloaded WooCommerce and i'm having a really strange issue with my permalinks. They are all set to default, however when I go to any of the pages the default link it brings me to brings up a blank page. The link looks like this:

http://primefitnessrx.com/wp/?page_id=464

However, if I remove the /wp/ prefix and have the link like this:

http://primefitnessrx.com/?page_id=464

It works perfectly. Anyone have any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a subdirectory called "wp"?  If so, my guess is that woocommerce hasn't been installed there, only on your base directory.

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction, thanks very much!